# Remove duplicates from CSS file

Tags: php, css, media-queries, unique, substr

Today I tried use SCCS Compiler (http://leafo.net/scssphp/) and i fell in love with this tool, but I need one more feature.

I generated compressed CSS file like that:

```
html,body{height:100%;}html,body{height:100%;}html,body{height:100%;}@media all and (max-width:960px){body{height:80%;width:95%;}}@media all and (max-width:480px){body{height:100%;width:90%;}}nav ul{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;}nav li{display:inline-block;}nav a{display:block;padding:6px 12px;text-decoration:none;}html,body{height:100%;}html,body{height:100%;}@media all and (max-width:960px){body{height:80%;width:95%;}}@media all and (max-width:480px){body{height:100%;width:90%;}}html,body{height:100%;}
```

Uncompressed file:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
@media all and (max-width: 960px) {
  body {
    height: 80%;
    width: 95%;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
  }
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
@media all and (max-width: 960px) {
  body {
    height: 80%;
    width: 95%;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
  }
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

I have this code in string variable in PHP and I need remove duplicates. It's sounds easy, array_unique and that's it. Of course. But i need unique code for normal css and for every media separately. So i need output:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
@media all and (max-width: 960px) {
  body {
    height: 80%;
    width: 95%;
  }
}
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

So this script don't remove html,body { height: 100% } from @media all and (max-width: 480px) because in this media is unique.

Could you help me?
If you can put every media queries at the end of the file I would be happy.

Comment: Did you ever figure out an answer to this? I have the same issue.

Comment: Oh, man. 9 years :D I don't remember if I resolve this problem :P

Answer (score 0):

you should use a css optimization like: https://github.com/GoalSmashers/clean-css

and I advise you to use Grunt in combination with scss and cleancss plugins for it instead of using PHP to parse your scss -> css, once you're used to it it's far easier to handle.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use only PHP :(